# Send onclick event of element without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swift3

I'm trying to automate through my Swift3 app the click of an HTML element in line2 which lacks an 'id'.

HTML portion from website containing desired element(line2)

```
<div id="actionButtons" style>
    <input class="pptbutton" onclick="return addSimResults();" title="SimulateRace" type="submit" value="Simulate">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="clearAllInputs();" style="font-size:0.8em" title="Clear all inputs">Clear All</a> = $0
    <div class="holder" style="font-size:0.8em;">
        <input class="pttbutton" id="graphButton" onclick="return addGraphResults();" style title="Graph your simulation" type="submit" value="Graph HvH">
...etc
```

---

I've successful automated line5's element.onclick event with the Swift code

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('graphButton').click();")
```

---

I've attempted to grab the element by Class name with Swift code

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('pptbutton')[0];") {
                (result, error) -> Void in
                print(result)
            }
```

which returns nil. I've also tried without the "[0]".

Any suggestions how I can cause line2's Element onclick Event?

Comment: have you tried `document.querySelector('.pptbutton')`?

Comment: have you tried `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('pptbutton')[0].click();")`?

Comment: @JoshuaK this worked!! ty so much

Comment: @JoshuaK do you want to put this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('pptbutton')[0];")
```

this line of code evaluates the javascript, defined as the given string. The String is pure Javascript which selects the first element within the dom with the css class pptbutton.

You forgot to call the click method on this element, so no click is triggered by your code.

It should be:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('pptbutton')[0].click();")
```

In this way the click event is triggered on the selected element.